# List of Publications

Tags: table-of-contents

Could you please provide suggestions on how to include a list of my publications in my PhD thesis? I would like it to appear at the end of the thesis, following the "References" section. Additionally, I would like the title "List of Publications" to be listed in the table of contents, with dotted lines connecting it to the corresponding page number.

Comment: Just add another chapter with title "List of Publications"?

Comment: For example `biblatex` provides the feature of adding several references to a document and also to list them to the table of contents. The name of each of these sections can be configured. So I would make the "References" and the "List of Publications" using `biblatex`. Alternatives would be packages like `multibib`. See the manuals for more information and if you have a problem in using one of them, please show a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).